# how can I make API KEY for Google Places api?

Tags: android, google-places-api, api-key

Here I have one problem that I can't access google places api service in android to find out nearby places.

i have read many tutorials but none of that clearly mention how to make a browser key or android key?

here i have tried all these.

1) make a browser key and pass in this query
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=YourAPIKey

2) made an android key and pass that key in same query but result is always same and show error as "access denied"

can anyone answer me how can I make this api key and which one(browser key or android key)?