# How do I get a Google Places API key for my Android App

Tags: android, api, google-maps, api-key, google-places

I've spent the last 48 hours pulling my hair out trying to find the answer to this question. The person who asked this question: [how can I make API KEY for Google Places api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128152/how-can-i-make-api-key-for-google-places-api)
Is experiencing the same issue I am having, but never got an answer.

Basically, I need help getting a Google PLACES api key. I already have a maps api key which works fine, but I cannot get a places API key. I have followed every single tutorial I could find including (To name a couple: (http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/) , (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/#) , (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PVK1Ue5rvk) But absolutely nothing has worked.

I added some screenshots below here to illustrate the problem:

1)
[image: 1]

2)
[image: 2]

3)
[image: 3]

4)
[image: 4]

Everyone I ask keeps telling me that it is just located somewhere on the https://console.developers.google.com website, but 2 solid days of looking has gotten me nowhere. Can someone please help me to find the EXACT location to obtain a places api? (Again, NOT a maps api, I already have that and am getting only REQUEST_DENIED errors due to my lack of a secondary key.

Answer (score 1):

Go your developer's console, there click on **Credentials**

[image: Create]

Then click on **enable api** on this page

[image: Enable api]

After that choose **Google Places** api

[image: Google Places]