# Start typing and get list of Addresses from Google in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

How can i get a list of addresses (street, av., etc) from Google?
I have seen some apps that you just start typing (waze for example) and it shows a list of adresses (probably from Google) that you can use to fill your search.
There is some API from Google that we can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try Google Places Api, check this out.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

There are heaps of info about how to use this Api, which is really simple.

[How do I get a Google Places API key for my Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302920/how-do-i-get-a-google-places-api-key-for-my-android-app)

Bye

Comment: Thats what i need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places)** (especially at **PlacePicker**).